# Creating a team project with Team Explorer using Team Foundation Server 2015

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

I'm looking for a way to do administrative tasks such creating new team projects having installed Team Foundation Server 2015 previously without having to install Visual Studio Community 2015. In older versions of TFS, I could use Team Explorer  for creating team projects but now which version of Team Explorer can I use to do it on TFS 2015?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Team Explorer is gone for 2015 "wave": ["we are not going to ship a Team Explorer 2015 stand-alone GUI"](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bharry/archive/2015/07/21/licensing-and-packaging-changes-for-tfs-2015.aspx).

To create a new team project you have to use Visual Studio 2015:
"Only the latest version has "full" compatibility with the latest Team Foundation Server, because this will be the only client that contains components that can interface with new features for that release, and will also be the only client from which you can perform certain administrative tasks such as creating new team projects" [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/Library/vs/alm/TFS/administer/requirements)

Answer (score 2):

You need at least Team Explorer installed. There's no way around it. The problem is that Microsoft isn't shipping Team Explorer 2015 as a stand-alone package. You can install Community and use that.

Once you have Team Explorer available, you can use the Team Foundation Power Tools to create a Team Project from the command line, though.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to install Visual Studio 2015 (8GB across all drives) for Team Explorer only you can follow the workaround explained in that article : http://www.sqlshack.com/wheres-my-team-explorer-2015/ basically by using an older version of Team Explorer and the Excel add-in